# Do we use "A is above B" when A is rather far from B?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-request, phrase-usage

[image]

See the picture, the flower pot is on a shelf and at a higher position the the TV. The pot is 5 meters away from the TV.

Is it correct to say "**The flower pot is above the TV**"?

This is because "**[above](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/above_1?q=above)**" mean "**at or to a higher place or position than something/somebody**"

So as long as the thing is at a higher position then we use "**above**"?

Do we use "**A is above B**" when A is rather far from B?

Comment: No, we say "higher than"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the situation in your picture, you should say that the picture is *higher* than the TV. That word has no implications about whether or not the items are vertically aligned.
If you use the word *above* in that situation, the hearer will think that the two lie on the same vertical line.

The same applies to the word *below* - it suggest vertical alignment.
If you want to emphasize that the items are exactly aligned, you can say *directly above* or *directly below*.